# create rotating list of password based on date in bash

Tags: bash

In my bash script that creates users with console in AWS, I have a standard password that I set for all users:

```
password="Welcome_Hello123!!!"
```

They are forced to change the password on first login.

I would like to vary that up based on date. How can I pull words from a file in bash and populate the password variable with a new word every two weeks?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something like this?

```
$ seq 50 | sed -n $(echo $(( $(date +"%V")/2 + 1)))p
20
```

use the week number divide by 2 so that it will change every two weeks.  Find the line from the that corresponds to the computed number.  You may want to write it this way

```
$ sed ... file
```